# Accessing information inside methods, Object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, oop, tweepy

I am trying to extract some information from a tweepy cursor object (containing twitter data).
The object contains a bunch of methods and attributes of which I have listed some below here,
text (attribute), retweet (attribute), favorited (method) ... etc. I am wondering how to access the information within the methods.
For example

```
#  I have created a class which authenticates and connects to te API, stream_live_tweets method returns iterable object. 
inst = GetTweets()
twObj = inst.stream_live_tweets(keyword = 'Killauea', num_tweets= 1)
for tweet in twObj:
    print(tweet.favorite)
```

out:
<bound method Status.favorite of Status(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x00000206E06EB6D8>, _json={'created_at': 'Tue Sep 29 18:31:23 +0000 2020', 'id': 1311010700437880838, 'id_str': '1311010700437880838', 'text': '@DenverWater coulda just said “not our fault” ', 'truncated': False, 'entities': {'hashtags': [], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions': [{'screen_name': 'DenverWater', 'name': 'Denver Water ', 'id': 18999734, 'id_str': '18999734', 'indices': [0, 12]}], 'urls': []}, **'metadata'**: {'iso_language_code': 'en', 'result_type': 'recent'}, 'source': 'Twitter for iPhone', 'in_reply_to_status_id': 1310998430940979200, 'in_reply_to_status_id_str': '1310998430940979200', 'in_reply_to_user_id': 1601204640, 'in_reply_to_user_id_str': '1601204640', 'in_reply_to_screen_name': 'killauea', 'user': {'id': 1601204640, 'id_str': '1601204640', **'name': 'YUNG POLY'**, 'screen_name': 'killauea', ...

I am wondering how to access the information within this method such as the 'name' for example (in bold)
tried accessing them similar to a dictionary or an attribute, but I get an `object is not subscriotable error`

```
  tweet.favorite['metadata']
  tweet.favorite.name
```

Any ideas if its possible to access this information?

Thanks

Comment: Try `dir(ttweet)` to see attributes. I suppose it is `tweet._json`. Use `some_data = json.loads(tweet._json)`  to deserialize the json data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a favorite.name attribute.

If there is, you have to access tweet attributes like in a Dict:

- Text of the tweet:
  `tweet['text']`
- Name of the user who made the action (tweeted, retweeted,
  etc):
  `tweet['user']['screen_name']`
- If it exists:
  `tweet['favorite']['name']`

If the tweet is not accessible, you can convert it to Dict using json module:

```
import json

for tweet in twObj:
   dict_tweet = json.loads(tweet)
```

And now you can access the different attributes of the tweet:

```
print(dict_tweet['favorited'])
print(dict_tweet['id'])
```